# rayshader: Plot coordinates of interest using ggplot2 doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, 3d, rayshader

I like to plot a 3D plot using `rayshader` package and put some coordinates of interest but it doesn't work.

If I make the dem elevation in `rayshader` example, it's OK:

```
library(rayshader)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)

#Here, I load a map with the raster package.
loadzip = tempfile() 
download.file("https://tylermw.com/data/dem_01.tif.zip", loadzip)
localtif = raster::raster(unzip(loadzip, "dem_01.tif"))
unlink(loadzip)


#And convert it to a matrix:
elmat = raster_to_matrix(localtif)

# Plot elevation
ggelmat = elmat %>%
 reshape2::melt() %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_tile(aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value)) +
 scale_x_continuous("X",expand = c(0,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous("Y",expand = c(0,0)) +
 coord_fixed()
ggelmat

# \donttest{
plot_gg(ggelmat, multicore = TRUE, raytrace = TRUE, width = 7, height = 4,
       scale = 300, windowsize = c(1400, 866), zoom = 0.6, phi = 30, theta = 30, show.legend = FALSE)
render_snapshot(clear = TRUE)
```

[image: img1]

But if I create some random point and try to put inside the plot:

```
#Create some 100 random coordinates
# grab 100 cell index numbers at random
samp <- sample(localtif, 100, replace = FALSE)

# and their location coordinates
samplocs <- xyFromCell(localtif, samp)
samplocs.df<-as.data.frame(samplocs)

pts<-spsample(localtif, 100, type = 'random')
pts.df<-as.data.frame(pts)

# Plot elevation with some coordinates
ggelmat2 = elmat %>%
 reshape2::melt() %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_point(data = samplocs.df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
 geom_tile(aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value)) +
 scale_x_continuous("X",expand = c(0,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous("Y",expand = c(0,0)) +
 coord_fixed()
ggelmat2

# \donttest{
plot_gg(ggelmat2, multicore = TRUE, raytrace = TRUE, width = 7, height = 4,
       scale = 300, windowsize = c(1400, 866), zoom = 0.6, phi = 30, theta = 30, show.legend = FALSE)
render_snapshot(clear = TRUE)
#
```

[image: img2]

It doesn't work! Another question, and I believe that's part of the solution, is it possible to show the original image system coordinates in the X and Y axis?

Comment: Before adding rayshader in the mix, what does `ggelmat2` look like? If this looks weird too, I would try rephrasing the question without the rayshader part for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elmat %>% reshape2::melt() %>% ggplot()` pattern causes the `Var1` and `Var2` columns of the plot input to be row and column numbers instead of coordinates. Also, your `samplelocs` were sampling values instead of cells from the `localtif` objects it seems.

I adressed these two points in the code below:

```r
library(rayshader)
#> Warning: package 'rayshader' was built under R version 4.0.2
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

#Here, I load a map with the raster package.
loadzip = tempfile() 
download.file("https://tylermw.com/data/dem_01.tif.zip", loadzip)
localtif = raster::raster(unzip(loadzip, "dem_01.tif"))
#> Warning in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO"): Discarded
#> datum Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid in CRS definition
unlink(loadzip)


#And convert it to a matrix:
elmat = raster_to_matrix(localtif)

samp <- sample(seq_along(localtif), 100, replace = FALSE)

# and their location coordinates
samplocs <- xyFromCell(localtif, samp)
samplocs.df<-as.data.frame(samplocs)

# Melt like this
df <- xyFromCell(localtif, seq_along(localtif))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$value <- as.vector(elmat)

# Plot elevation with some coordinates
ggelmat2 = df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y =y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) +
  geom_point(data = samplocs.df) +
  scale_x_continuous("X",expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Y",expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_fixed()
ggelmat2
```

[image]